# I want to display the last 4 pages in Yii?

Tags: php, yii

Studying Programming Yii, I want to display the last 4 pages:

**SiteController.php**

```
public function actionStart() 
    {
        $featured = Page::model()->findAllByAttributes(
            array(),
            $condition  = 'featured = :featureId',
            $params     = array(
                ':featureId' => 1,
            )
        );
        $this->render('/layouts/start/start', array('featured'=>$featured));
    }
```

**/layouts/start/start.php**

```
 <?php print_r($this->featured); ?>
```

The latter file does not display anything, and should be an array with the data, how do I get it?

Comment: i think you should read documentation first. You can't have start.php for SiteController. As per Yii rules your start.php should reside in views of Site.

Comment: You have to output the featured variable using a cgridview or some kind of grid that yii has built in, it's pretty easy but as @Namelus said, read the docs to find out how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$this->render('/layouts/start/start', array('featured'=>$featured));
```

Here, you are sending array(association array) of values to the **View**. You can access these values by calling the array `Key`.

So, your code should be

```
<?php echo print_r($featured); ?>
```

**Another example.**

```
$this->render('myView', array('myName'=>'Hearaman','myAge'=>25));
```

I'm sending my name and age to View. To show my name and age, i should call the keys

```
echo $myName;
echo $myAge;
```

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate the $this for featured.

```
<?php echo print_r($featured, true); ?>
```